# Why does PSeq.map with computation expression seem to hang?

Tags: f#, computation-expression

I'm writing a scraper using [`FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq`](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq/) and a [retry computation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5942142/300908). I would like to retrieve HTML from multiple pages in parallel, and I would like to retry requests when they fail.

For example:

```
open System
open FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq

type RetryBuilder(max) = 
  member x.Return(a) = a               // Enable 'return'
  member x.Delay(f) = f                // Gets wrapped body and returns it (as it is)
                                       // so that the body is passed to 'Run'
  member x.Zero() = failwith "Zero"    // Support if .. then 
  member x.Run(f) =                    // Gets function created by 'Delay'
    let rec loop(n) = 
      if n = 0 then failwith "Failed"  // Number of retries exceeded
      else try f() with _ -> loop(n-1)
    loop max

let retry = RetryBuilder(4)

let getHtml (url : string) = retry { 
    Console.WriteLine("Get Url")
    return 0;
}

//A property/field?
let GetHtmlForAllPages = 
    let pages = {1 .. 10}
    let allHtml = pages |> PSeq.map(fun x -> getHtml("http://somesite.com/" + x.ToString())) |> Seq.toArray
    allHtml

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let htmlForAllPages = GetHtmlForAllPages
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

When I try to interact with `GetHtmlForAllPages` from `main` the code seems to hang. Stepping through the code shows me that `PSeq.map` begins work on the first four values of `pages`.

What's going on that causes the `retry` computation expression to never start/complete? Is there some weird interplay between `PSeq` and `retry`?

The code works as expected if I make `GetHtmlForAllPages` a function and invoke it. I'm curious what's going on when `GetHtmlForAllPages` is a field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're deadlocking within a static constructor. The scenario is described [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/661823/static-constructor-and-deadlock):

> The CLR uses an internal lock to ensure that static constructor:
>
> - is only called once
> - gets executed before creation of any instance of the
>   class or before accessing any static members.
>
> With this behaviour of
> CLR, there is a potential opportunity of a deadlock if we perform any
> asynchronous blocking operation in a static constructor. (...)
>
> The main thread will wait for the helper thread to complete within the
> static constructor. Since the helper thread is accessing the instance
> method, it will first try to acquire the internal lock. As internal
> lock is already acquired by the main thread, we will end-up in a
> deadlock situation.

Using Parallel LINQ (or any other similar library like FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq) in a static constructor will make you run into that problem.

Unfortunately, a static constructor of a compiler-generated class is what you get for your `GetHtmlForAllPages` value. From ILSpy (with C# formatting):

```
namespace <StartupCode$ConsoleApplication1>
{
    internal static class $Program
    {
        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        internal static readonly Program.RetryBuilder retry@17;

        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        internal static readonly int[] GetHtmlForAllPages@24;

        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerNonUserCode, CompilerGenerated]
        internal static int init@;

        static $Program()
        {
            $Program.retry@17 = new Program.RetryBuilder(4);
            IEnumerable<int> pages = Operators.OperatorIntrinsics.RangeInt32(1, 1, 10);
            ParallelQuery<int> parallelQuery = PSeqModule.map<int, int>(new Program.allHtml@26(), pages);
            ParallelQuery<int> parallelQuery2 = parallelQuery;
            int[] allHtml = SeqModule.ToArray<int>((IEnumerable<int>)parallelQuery2);
            $Program.GetHtmlForAllPages@24 = allHtml;
        }
    }
}
```

and in your actual `Program` class:

```
[CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.Value)]
public static int[] GetHtmlForAllPages
{
    get
    {
        return $Program.GetHtmlForAllPages@24;
    }
}
```

That's where the deadlock is coming from.

As soon as you change `GetHtmlForAllPages` to be a function (by adding `()`) it is no longer part of that static constructor, which makes the program work as expected.